# Background url disappearing on animation in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, animation

Currently have a problem where animating on background position with a background-url throws the image to disappear. The error can be seen here in this pen: http://codepen.io/raksonibs/pen/oYPryd

I tried everything I could google and think of on the element and its parent. Here are some examples of solutions I tried:

```
#case-opener-scrollbox {
    // -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        // -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        // will-change: background;
        // will-change: background-position;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        position: static;
}
```

Anyone got any idea as to why this momentary disapperance occurs?

Comment: I don't notice any disappearance - Chrome 54.0.2840.100

Comment: btw. valid comment in css is `/* ... */`

Comment: Hey @Sojtin, let the animation run a few times. here is a video of it: http://recordit.co/XaUGfnRTMX